# Area between 2 parabolas

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the area between $y^2=4-x$ and $y^2=4-4x$

So the graph is:

[image]

The limit of integration are $2\int_{0}^{2}\int^{4-y^2}_{\frac{4-y^2}{4}}dxdy$

But what should be the integrand?

Comment: Double integral? Integrate $1$. The inner integral, after integrating $1$, will become the difference between upper and lower limits. This will result in a familiar single integral of the difference in heights between the two curves, if you interpret height with your head turned sideways.

Comment: Solve both equations for x and calculate the $\int_{y_{lower}}^{y_{upper}}(x_1-x_2)dy$, with $x_1=4-y^2$ and $x_2=1-0.25y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options:

- Using the symmetry around the line $y = 0$, so the restrictions are functions, then doubling the result $$A = 2 \left(\int\limits_0^4 y_1(x)\, dx - \int\limits_0^1 y_2(x) \, dx\right)$$
- Exchanging $x$ and $y$ coordinates and integrate the difference there $$A = \int\limits_{-2}^2 \left( x_1(y) - x_2(y) \right) \, dy$$

where $y_1: y^2=4-x$ and $y_2: y^2=4-4x$.